# How do I handle the below json data from a form made up of tabular divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a form in which the data is made up of divs in a table like layout. Each row is considered a record but when I get the serializeArray values there doesn't seem a way to distinctly separate out each row. Below is a snippet of the div structure, then an example of serialized data returned.  First the div structure.

```
<div id="mainnotetocodediv">
<div id="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="installnoteid" value="1">                         
    <label class="blockinline width-800"></label>
    <input type="text" name="ksinotecode" class="width-75" value="r">
</div> 
<div id="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="installnoteid" value="2"> 
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" name="ksinotecode" class="width-75" value="r">
</div> 
<div id="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="installnoteid" value="3">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" name="ksinotecode" class="width-75" value="r">
</div> 
<div id="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="installnoteid" value="4">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" name="ksinotecode" class="width-75" value="r">
</div>
```

Now here is the array returned in the console log. I structured how each row should logically layed out.

```
[{"name":"installnoteid","value":"1"},{"name":"ksinotecode","value":"r"}
,{"name":"installnoteid","value":"2"},{"name":"ksinotecode","value":"r"}
,{"name":"installnoteid","value":"3"},{"name":"ksinotecode","value":"r"}
,{"name":"installnoteid","value":"4"},{"name":"ksinotecode","value":"r"}]
```

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: The above data is the actual data in the console log. I just put the line breaks for each record for readability.

Answer (score 0):

make all the input name as array

like below i have added for one `<div>`

```
<div id="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="installnoteid['one'][]" value="1">                         
    <label class="blockinline width-800"></label>
    <input type="text" name="ksinotecode['one'][]" class="width-75" value="r">
</div>
```

Comment: Does each interaction of the name have to be one, two, three etc?

Comment: yes you have add one ,two, three etc